# Relatively Prime problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime integers then $b$ and $a$ plus some multiple of $b$ are also relatively prime. I can see how it works for concrete examples but can't prove it. i.e. $(a,b)=1$ implies $(b,a+kb)=1$.

Comment: hint: euclidean algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $d$ divides $b$ and $a+kb$

$d$ will divide $a+kb-k\cdot b=a$ as $k$ is an integer

$\displaystyle \implies d$ will divide $(a,b)=1$